# Does (ant-contrib) propertyregex support multiple uses from the same property?

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I'm attempting to use a property as a template for multiple other properties, but it only works the first time. It's probably easiest to show by example, so I've cut down my code to a minimal case that exhibits this behaviour:

```
<target name="test">
    <property name="individual.template" value="x@ID@"/>

    <propertyregex property="individual.1" input="${individual.template}" regexp="\@ID\@" replace="1" global="true" override="true"/>
    <echo>====== ${individual.1} ::: ${individual.template}</echo>
    <propertyregex property="individual.2" input="${individial.template}" regexp="\@ID\@" replace="2" global="true" override="true"/>
    <echo>====== ${individual.2} ::: ${individual.template}</echo>
    <propertyregex property="individual.3" input="${individial.template}" regexp="\@ID\@" replace="3" global="true" override="true"/>
    <echo>====== ${individual.3} ::: ${individual.template}</echo>
    <propertyregex property="individual.4" input="${individial.template}" regexp="\@ID\@" replace="4" global="true" override="true"/>
    <echo>====== ${individual.4} ::: ${individual.template}</echo>
    <propertyregex property="individual.5" input="${individial.template}" regexp="\@ID\@" replace="5" global="true" override="true"/>
    <echo>====== ${individual.5} ::: ${individual.template}</echo>
</target>
```

I would expect this to output x1, x2, etc., but it outputs the following:

```
 [echo] ====== x1 ::: x@ID@
 [echo] ====== ${individual.2} ::: x@ID@
 [echo] ====== ${individual.3} ::: x@ID@
 [echo] ====== ${individual.4} ::: x@ID@
 [echo] ====== ${individual.5} ::: x@ID@
```

As you can see it's ok for the first one, but the next properties are simply not set. I thought at first that the template property was modified, but as you can see from the output, that's not the case. Am I just doing something silly here? Is this not supported? Or is it a bug? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

(Ant version 1.8.2, ant-contrib version 1.0b2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@thor84no, I see a copy/paste error in the test case: Shouldn't you be printing the value of `individual.1/individual.2/individual.3/individual.4/individual.5` instead of `individual.template`? I made these changes locally and the output is what you had expected:

```
test:
     [echo] ====== x1 ::: x1
     [echo] ====== x2 ::: x2
     [echo] ====== x3 ::: x3
     [echo] ====== x4 ::: x4
     [echo] ====== x5 ::: x5
```

Comment: Thank god I was just doing something stupid. I don't know how I managed to do that, and I certainly don't understand how I missed it when I was printing the same value out on the lines in between... I was just so fixated on the 1/2/.. variables I didn't really look at the template one. Thanks a lot for pointing out my temporary retardation!

Answer (score 3):

It's just a typo: (individ **i** al) vs. (individ **u** al)